# Which probability in this hypothesis test?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-theory

We have a hypothesis A (null hypothesis) such that $p\le 0.6$ and B such that $p>0.6$.
Now we want to develop a deterministic test $\phi$ for 20 people that has a safety of 95%.

Hence we would be interested in looking for a test that gets the error that we take $B$ but actually have A small.

This one is given by $\sum_{k=0}^{200} \phi(k) \binom {200}{k} 0.6^k 0.4^{1-k}$

Now we have to choose a minimal $c \in \{0,...200\}$ such that $\phi$ is zero at every point less than $c$ and 1 elsewhere such that $\sum_{k=0}^{200} \phi(k) \binom {200}{k} 0.6^k 0.4^{1-k} \le 0.05$ cause of the safety requirement.

Now one needs to solve this, but this is not my question.

My question is: Why is it alright to just look at the value $p=0.6$ in the restriction of the error in $\sum_{k=0}^{200} \phi(k) \binom {200}{k} 0.6^k 0.4^{1-k} \le 0.05$, as the null hypothesis actually suggests a $p \le 0.6$, so in principle looking at 
$\sum_{k=0}^{200} \phi(k) \binom {200}{k} 0.5^k 0.5^{1-k} \le 0.05$ is reasonable too.

My problem is that I think that my calculation is only reasonable if the null hypothesis $A$ would be $p=0.6$ and $B$ $p>0.6$. But what do we do in this case?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, the reason we're choosing $p=0.6$ is because that's the "worst" situation you could be in (in terms of this error you're trying to avoid).  If you can find a $c$ that works for $0.6$, it will automatically work for any smaller $p$ as well.

You're accumulating probabilities in the right tail of a binomial distribution, and those will be larger for a larger $p$ than for a smaller $p$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that this maximizes it? Since we have that $x(1-x) \le (\frac{1}{2})^2$ for $x \in [0,1]$, my first idea would be that one would always have to look at p=0.5 in this case.

Comment: But you very rarely have equal exponents: you have $0.6^k 0.4^{200-k}$ and for $k$ close to 200 that will be bigger than $0.5^k 0.5^{200-k}$. (We're looking in the right tail of a binomial distribution, and you want to push the peak as far to the right as you can.)